# How can I get the next char in my string with the stringreader in Java?

Tags: java, string, char, stringreader

Consider this code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    String name = "(My name is Bob)(I like computers)"

    StringReader s = new StringReader(name);

    try {
        // This is the for loop that I don't know 
        for () {
            String result = "";  
            // Here the char has to be appended to the String result.
        }
        System.out.println("The string is: " + result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.toString();
    }
}
```

What I am looking for is a for-loop that first looks at the character at the current position and then appends it to a string if that character is not ")". However, the char ")" should also be appended to the string. In this example the output should be:

The string result is: (My name is Bob)

Comment: I didnt get you question. What you want is a substring between the first brackets right?

Comment: I want to look at each character in the string name and return the part of the string that comes before ")". The char ")" however should also be in that string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a working solution.

```
import java.io.StringReader;

public class Re {
public static void main (String[] args) {
String name = "(My name is Bob)(I like computers)";

StringReader s = new StringReader(name);

try {
    // This is the for loop that I don't know
    String result = "";
    int c = s.read();
    for (;c!= ')';) {
        result = result + (char)c;
        // Here the char has to be appended to the String result.
        c = s.read();
    }
    result = result + ')';
    System.out.println("The string is: " + result);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.toString();
}

}
}
```

Comment: I have done the way you want, though it has some performance issues. For example instead of using String for result you could use StringBuffer.

Comment: are you sure that this part: 'for (;c!= ')';) {' works? I think that you have to use the ascii code instead of ')'

Answer (score 0):

Based upon your comment, I believe you dont require to parse the entire string, henceforth I suggest you the following answer

```
    String name = "(My name is Bob(I like computers";
    int firstCloseBracket = name.indexOf(")");
    String result=null;
    if(-1!=firstCloseBracket){
        result = name.substring(0,firstCloseBracket+1);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```

Hope this solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = "(My name is Bob)(I like computers)";
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
        result = result + name.charAt(i);
        if (name.charAt(i) == ')') {
            System.out.println(result);
            result = "";
        }
    }

}
```

Try this. Is this what you want to do ?
This will prints the substring before ")" as you wrote in comment above.